# I saw turbo_stream_from not working on existing rails app upgraded to 7.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

This app never used action cable or redis before, I upgraded to rails 7.0.0 from 5.0 today to try `turbo_stream_from` for the first time.

It looks like working on the rails console, because I see `Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob` is being enqueued and performed when I create a record. But

I generated a sample 7.0.0 app and tried to find differences. I added two files `app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb` and `app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb`. I have `config/cable.yml` as below

```yaml
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: old_app_production
```

Is there any additional setting needed for old apps? I wish there was `rails actioncable:install`. I am still learning, please help. Ah, for the sample app I followed a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpWFrUwAN88

Comment: Just learned this command `rails importmap:install` ‍♂️

Comment: And, I need to add `"@hotwired/turbo-rails"` to get it working.

Comment: Did you get it working?  I followed the same video as you, but my views are not updating live.  And I did check that @hotwired is in my application.js file.

Comment: I added `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` to `app/javascript/application.js` to be exact